# Function not working in for loop

Tags: r

Kind of a beginner question here: I have a function, `cos.dissim` that I'm using to compute the dissimilarity between two vectors and it works fine when I call it by itself with a set value like this:

```
doc.number = 1
cos.dissim(doc.matrix[doc.number, ], SK$prototype[SK$cluster[doc.number], ])
```

But when I try to put it in a loop to check all 30 documents, the code does nothing. I don't get an error message of any kind, the code just doesn't output anything.

```
dissim.tot = function(){  
  for(x in 1:30){
    doc.number = x
    cos.dissim(doc.matrix[doc.number, ], SK$prototype[SK$cluster[doc.number], ])
  }
}
```

Am I missing something obvious here? I'm new to the language and Haven't created many `for` loops.

Comment: Do you just want to print the result? If so, then wrap your command in `print(cos.dissim(...))`. When you're inside of a loop automatic printing is disabled (which is usually what you want anyway)

Comment: I'm trying to get all the results into a matrix but thank you for letting me know this. I thought the loop wasn't working at all but now I'm seeing the results.

Answer (score 1):

`for` returns `NULL`, so for your approach to work, you need to assign the outcome of each pass through the loop to an object.

For example:

```
sqr <- function(x) x^2 # square x

f <- function() {
  y <- numeric() # initialize the output vector
  for (i in 1:10) {
    y <- c(y, sqr(i)) # append the square of i to y
  }
  return(y)
}

f()

#  [1]   1   4   9  16  25  36  49  64  81 100
```

That said, something like this should also work:

```
sapply(1:30, cos.dissim, doc.matrix[i, ], SK$prototype[SK$cluster[i], ])
```